# What is the time complexity of this 5-line Java algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, big-o

This is a solution to the following [problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/flip-game-ii/description/)

Basically, you have a string of '-' and '+' characters:

> ++-++++

You flip two consecutive '+' into '-', then your friend does the same, then back to you, and so on. Once someone can't make a move, they lose.

So for the above game, if you go first, you win by flipping either the last two '+', or the middle two '+' (think about it).

Here is an algorithm that solves whether or not the player going first wins:

```
public boolean canWin(String s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length() - 1; ++i)
        if (s.charAt(i) == '+' && s.charAt(i + 1) == '+' && 
            !canWin(s.substring(0, i) + "--" + s.substring(i + 2)))
                return true;
    return false;
}
```

Basically, the algorithm recursively says "The player going first wins if he can reduce the board to a state where the player going first loses".

Here's my thoughts on time complexity:

Let N be the number of characters on the board.

At worst, there are N-1 moves (if all '+'). Each move makes the board (at worst) only 2 moves smaller.

But then I get stuck. I know it is worse than N * (N-2) * (N-4) * ... * 1, but I can't formulate it.

Comment: Your series `N..1` gets called up to `N` times, so it's N^2, I think.

Comment: it's much worse than that (think fibonacci)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the worst case, the first player cannot win and the loop will go through all iterations. Taking the problem size, n, to be the number of pluses in the input string, we have a runtime of T(n)=(n-1)T(n-2)=(n-1)(n-3)T(n-4)=...=O(n!!). Here, n!! is the double factorial. This is significantly worse than exponential, which for this problem is rather terrible. You could improve this bound quite a bit using dynamic programming as follows:

```
Set<String, Boolean> canWinMap = new HashMap<>();

public boolean canWin(String s) {
    if (canWinMap.hasKey(s)) {
        return canWinMap.get(s);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length() - 1; ++i)
        if (s.charAt(i) == '+' && s.charAt(i + 1) == '+' && 
            !canWin(s.substring(0, i) + "--" + s.substring(i + 2)))
                canWinMap.put(s, true);
                return true;
    canWinMap.put(s, false);
    return false;
}
```

Then the worst-case is bounded by an exponential (possibly times a linear term), since there are only O(2^n) possible strings derived from the starting string containing '+' and '-'. After this, all recursive calls are constant-time (amortized).